# Javascript is redirecting to wrong url

Tags: javascript

```
function OpenModalReplyAllDialog(url, SubscriberId,ActualText) {
    //Todo: Cleanup the unnecessary code.
    var returnValue = new ModalReturnValue(null, null, null);
    var retVal = null;
    var urlredirect = url + '/UC_5_0_0.aspx?GroupId=' + SubscriberId + '&messageText=' + ActualText;
    returnValue = openToolbarModal(urlredirect, 342, 450, null, 'scroll:no;resizable:yes;status:no;center:yes');

    return true;
}
```

When I don't select the menu the url is:

```
 be/UC_5_0_0.aspx?GroupId=' + SubscriberId + '&messageText=' + ActualText
```

but when I select the menu it's becoming:

```
 be/be/UC_5_0_0.aspx?GroupId=' + SubscriberId + '&messageText=' + ActualText
```

I want always redirect to

```
 be/UC_5_0_0.aspx?GroupId=' + SubscriberId + '&messageText=' + ActualText
```

Comment: Where is your url variable coming from? that would be setting the `be/` or `be/be/` part of your redirect url

Comment: its coming from code in variable url

Comment: can you provide that code?

Comment: So pass the correct value in the parameter.... as easy as this

Comment: I think your actual problem is that you need to use `/be` (with a prepended slash to symbolize that this is relative to the root) or use the `<base />` html tag.

Comment: i think its though microsoftajax.js its adding extra data

Comment: i even tried /be but no use

Comment: var URL = products.FirstOrDefault().ProductName;
                                //Fix for XT-2136
                                URL = Regex.Replace(URL, @"\s+", "");

                                SubscriberId = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Encrypt(SubscriberId));
                                btnReply.Attributes.Add("onclick", ControlUtilities.GetSanitizedClientScript("javascript:return OpenModalReplyDialog('{0}', '{1}');", URL, SubscriberId));

Comment: function openModalReply(url, width, height) {
    var returnValue = new ModalReturnValue(null, null, null);
    returnValue = window.showModalDialog(url, self, 'center:yes;status:no;unadorned:yes;help:no;dialogHeight:' + height + 'px;dialogWidth:' + width + 'px;resizable:yes;');

    if (returnValue != null) {
        if (returnValue.Command == "TimeOut")
            redirectToUrl(returnValue.Url);
        else
            return returnValue;
    }
    else
        return returnValue;
} can be because of self

Comment: because of self is it giving wrong url please help